# MudBlazor - Searchable MudTextField with suggestions

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

I am trying to create a **searchable textfield** in **MudBlazor** with **suggestions list**.
However i am trying display the suggestions with MudList but the list seems to show the suggestions after a delay. Is there a better solutions other than MudList?
My solution can be accessed [here](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOwRYbETTZKsZNSn)

I would appreciate any feedback

Comment: Seems very similar to `<MudAutocomplete>`.

Comment: "but the list seems to show the suggestions after a delay" suggests that whatever method you are calling to update the list is slow, probably not the component.  Difficult to tell without any code.